# Inequality with summation

Tags: inequality, summation, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a_i$ positive numbers and $n\ge2$ (the subscripts are taken modulo $n$), how can I prove the following inequality  $n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-1)a_k+a_{k+1}}\le\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}$ ?

Comment: Considering that $[(n-1)a_k + a_{k+1}]^{-1} = [na_k + (a_{k+1} - a_k)]^{-1}$ is greater than $[na_k]^{-1}$ when the sequence $\{a_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing, there is no way in this case that this inequality holds. Perhaps you mean that the sequence is increasing, in which case the corresponding argument makes the inequality rather clear?

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $$n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(n-1)a_k+a_{k+1}}\leq\frac{n}{(n-1+1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{(n-1)a_k}+\frac{1^2}{a_{k+1}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{n-1}{a_k}+\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{n-1}{a_k}+\frac{1}{a_k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k}.$$